# Can‘t stash in SourceTree

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree

I have a problem, when I try to stash my changes on a source tree or when using the git terminal (from source tree) I get this error

```
"fatal: cannot handle stash as a builtin"
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To solve it I changed Options->Git->Git Version from 'Embedded' to 'System' and it worked when I moved back to 'Embedded'

[image]